# Need help in understanding how I can implement subscribe properly

Tags: angular, typescript

### Scenario

For my project I need to make two calls to a http service, I call both in one function: `getData()`. I need information of both Arrays to parse it into another object.

One service call is called

- `getObjectData()`

In this function I'll call the service corresponding to a ID. I'll get an array back with Objects. I need Object Id and the Name of this object.

- `getSensorData()`

Each ObjectId also has a DeviceID with SensorData so, logically I do a for loop for each ID in order to get the corresponding data. The data is an array so I'll need information of each sensorData in `sensorData[]`.

```
objects: TableData[];
otamObjects: OtamObject[];
sensorData: SensorData[];
```

So in conclusion I want to have a `TableData[]` filled with data that I can then use for filling a table.

### Code:

I have the following code for this in a component.ts

```
getData(): void {
    this.objects = new Array<TableData>();
    this.service.getObjectData(1)
        .subscribe(otamObject => {
            this.otamObjects = otamObject;
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.otamObjects));
            for (let item of this.otamObjects) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(item));
                var object = new TableData();
                object.Name = item.Name;
                object.ObjectId = item.OtamObjectId;
                (console.log('Create a new object' + JSON.stringify(object)));
                this.service.getSensorData(item.DeviceId)
                    .subscribe(response => {
                        for (let item of response) { // Forgive me for the following hard coded strings.                            
                            if (item.Key === 'Latitude') {
                                object.Latitude = item.Value;
                            }
                            if (item.Key === 'Longitude') {
                                object.Longitude = item.Value;
                            }
                            if (item.Key === 'Battery') {
                                object.Latitude = item.Value;
                            }
                            if (item.Key === 'Charging') {
                                object.Charging = item.Value;
                            }
                            if (item.Key === 'LocationType'){
                                if (item.Value === '1'){
                                    object.LocationType = "GPS";
                                } else {
                                    object.LocationType = "GSM";
                                }
                            }
                            object.LastActvity = item.CreatedDate;
                            console.log('Second for loop has finished: ' 
                            + JSON.stringify(object));                              
                        }
                        this.objects.push(object);
                        console.log("Second For loop has finished, pushing this object: " + JSON.stringify(object) + 
                        " to the array of objects: " + JSON.stringify(this.objects))
                    }, error => { console.log(<any>error); })
            }
            console.log('End of the first for loop, with data in Objects: ' + JSON.stringify(this.objects));
        },
        error => {
            console.log(<any>error);
        }
        );
};
```

In the services I 'll make the calls:

```
getObjectData(companyId: number): Observable<OtamObject[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.actionUrl + "otamObject/" + companyId, this.headers)
        .map((response: Response) => <OtamObject[]>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

getSensorData(deviceId: number): Observable<SensorData[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.actionUrl + "sensorData/deviceId/" + deviceId, this.headers)
        .map((response: Response) => <SensorData[]>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

### Problem

The reason why I made this question is that now, as you can see in the output[image], the first for loop is finished before everything else, but this is not what I want. I want to have three objects and then he needs to do the second for loop for each object.

I don't fully understand how I can fix this, in any other programming language the first for loop should wait before the last so it would just do it but because I got the subcribe it just finish the loop. I understand it has to do with the second subscribe. Anyway, what is the correct way to handle this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop will not wait for a subscribe to be finished. Because the observable function is ran async. Might want to use something like the `async` library add a callback to the for loop.

Comment: Can be fixed with `mergeMap` or similar operators

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, Your answer made me look for the correct operation and the answer. While the provided is 'fine', I guess, I believe it's not very good practice to not use the correct tools available and use another third party library. Yet another dependency.